# How do I create an action that changes the properties of a specific uicollectionviewcell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, swift4, uicollectionviewcell

I have an app with a UICollectionView. Each custom cell has a circular progress view and a button that's supposed to up its progress, but I can't figure out how to change the properties for the specific cell's subviews inside the button action.

I've tried

- adding a target to the button inside the "cellForItemAt indexPath" function, but then how to call for that specific cell inside the target's function.
- adding a IBAction inside the custom cell class, but same problem again

Basically the problem is how can you call for a specific cell at a certain index path outside the "cellForItemAt" function?

Comment: You don't want to attempt to update the specific specific cell's subview by grabbing it from a cell that's visible. You want to update the underlying data that the cell determines its progress from and then reload the cells at the appropriate index paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup your UICollectionViewCell subclass something like this:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    var buttonAction: (() -> Void)?

    @IBAction func didPressButton() {
        buttonAction?()
    }

}
```

and in your UITableViewDelegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "your identifier", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.buttonAction = {
        //Do whatever you wish
    }
    ...
    ...
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but something weird happened. Whenever I clicked the add button, it added on the cell below then the cell and back and forth it went.

Comment: In the closure I simply said    cell.servingsEaten += 1 this is a nutrition app btw and self.collectionView.reloadData() which updates the label thru cell.label.text = "\(servingsEaten)..."

Comment: Try keeping states of the cell separately, so when you call `reloadData()` your cells can be reconfigured. E.g. you can reset your cells appearance in `prepareForReuse()` method and then reconfigure it accordingly in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a target to the button inside the `cellForItemAt indexPath` function, also send the index path as a tag with the button function like:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "your identifier", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.buttonAction = {
            //Do whatever you wish
        }
        ...
        ...
        **cell.button.tag = indexPath.row**
        return cell
    }
```

Then the function in which you have set as target, you need to update that particular cell to update UI by writing the below code

```
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[Sender.tag]];
```